# How to import files from specific directory, not using os.path in Python

Tags: python, variables, directory

So far my code is this :

```
from glob import glob
shakedir='D:\report\shakeall'
from shakedir import isfile
def countwords(fp):
   with open(fp) as fh:
       return len(fh.read().split())
print "There are" ,sum(map(countwords, filter(isfile, glob("*.txt") ) ) ), "words in the files."
```

The problem is this code doesn't work :)

I'm not used to Python grammar, so I just tried anything.

What I want is, I want this script to import text files from specific directory.

Not from the `os.path`, where my .py file is.

I want to import from `D:\report\shakeall` and I can't. That's it.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: i dont think that os.path does what you think it does... :S
also - didnt i already answer this for you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842548/how-do-i-count-unique-words-of-text-files-in-specific-directory-with-python/11842758#11842758

Comment: possible duplicate of [I don't understand the 'from' in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865835/i-dont-understand-the-from-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `glob` function alone for this purpose:

```
from glob import glob

pattern = "D:\\report\\shakeall\\*.txt"
filelist = glob(pattern)
```

and then do whatever you want on that filelist. Your way should work now:

```
def countwords(fp):
    with open(fp) as fh:
        return len(fh.read().split())

print "There are" ,sum(map(countwords, filelist))), "words in the files."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk("pathname")` to get a list of files in a certain directory.
http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.walk

Answer (score 0):

**backslashes** signify an *escape* in a string literal. Try either

```
"d:/report/shakeall"
```

Or

```
"d:\\report\\shakeall"
```

Ideally:

```
os.path.join("d:", "report/", "shakeall")
```

Comment: Or a raw string - r"d:\report"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is:

```
shakedir = "d:\\report\\shakeall"
..
print "There are" ,sum(map(countwords, filter(isfile, glob(shakedir + "\\*.txt"))))), ".."
                                                           ^^^^^ It can take directories too..
```

The line:

```
from shakedir import isfile
```

does not make any sense to me. And provide an implementation for isfile, or use the one from os module.

Comment: umm..what I just wanted to import files from that directory and simply did in that way. sorry for that.