# I don't understand the 'from' in Python

Tags: python, glob

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import isfile
def countwords(fp):
   with open(fp) as fh:
       return len(fh.read().split())

print "There are" ,sum(map(countwords, filter(isfile, glob("*.txt") ) ) ), "words in the files."
```

in the first line, why don't this just simply import glob library?

Is there any reason for using "from glob" in front of "import glob"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write `import glob`, you would need to use `glob.glob`.

`from glob import glob` takes `glob.glob` and makes it available as just `glob`.

Comment: Agreed. I use the "from" keyword mostly for convenience, but sometime it's necessary in order to avoid name clashes.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import glob
>>> dir(glob)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 
 'fnmatch', 'glob', 'glob0', 'glob1', 'has_magic', 'iglob', 'magic_check', 
 'os', 're', 'sys']
```

You can see all of the functions in the glob module here, you may for example want an iterator version of glob and in that case you would use:

```
from glob import iglob
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use `import glob`, for the function `glob("*.txt")`, you have to write `glob.glob("*.txt")`.

basically, the first `glob` in the `from glob import glob` is the name of the module, while the second one is the name of the function.

Answer (score 2):

`from glob import glob` will import `glob` attribute of `glob` module when `import glob` will import whole module

Answer (score 2):

This link seemed to explain all of the different variations quite well:

http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

The bottom line is that importing a specific thing from a module gives you a direct reference to ONLY that thing and not the whole module.

Answer (score 1):

When you have `import` glob, you import all the functions from that module. When you have `from xyz import abc`, you're only importing the `abc` function from the `xyz` module. In this case, you're importing the `glob` function from the `glob` module.

This way, in the Python code, if you want to use the `glob` function, instead of writing `glob.glob`, you only have to write `glob`.